# Expresión regular para validar formato moneda

Tags: javascript, regex

soy nuevo con respecto al uso de `regex` y me encuentro realizando validaciones con `javascript` para los campos que únicamente posean el formato `${1,3}.{3}....` como por ejemplo `$1.250.000`, pudiendo ser este número lo más largo posible.

La siguiente es mi Expresión regular
`^$[0-9]{1,3}([\\.][0-9]{3})`

Esta expresión no está repitiendo la parte posterior al `{1,3}` pero según lo que leí si debería arrojarme `true` al momento de validar la siguiente expresión:

```
console.log(/^$[0-9]{1,3}([\\.][0-9]{3})/.test("$50.000"))
```

pero su resultado es `false`.

y para poder "repetir" cierta parte de la expresión tengo entendido que se utiliza `*` por lo que creo que mi expresión debería quedar así:

```
console.log(/^$[0-9]{1,3}([\\.]*[0-9]{3})/.test("$50.000.000"))
```

pero esto también retorna `false`. Y si quedara de esta manera

```
console.log(/^$[0-9]{1,3}*([\\.][0-9]{3})/.test("$50.000.000"))
```

retorna `Invalid regular expression: /^$[0-9]{1,3}*([\\.][0-9]{3})/: Nothing to repeat`.

Si me pudieran orientar o ayudar para poder generar bien mi `regex` se los agradezco.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el **$**, necesitas escaparlo puesto que se trata de un carácter reservado propio de las expresiones regulares. La expresión debería quedarte así:

```js
console.log(/^\$[0-9]{1,3}([\\.][0-9]{3})/.test("$50.000"))
```

Comment: jaja por la cosa que no funcionaba, muchas gracias :D, entonces debo escapar cualquier carácter especial ?

Comment: Solamente los que tengan su propia utilidad dentro de las expresiones regulares: Ejemplos: ^{}[]()$, etc En caso de que estos quieras que sean tratados como un literal dentro de la cadena. En tu caso, como quieres que tu cadena comience por el literal **$** tienes escaparlo para diferenciarlo del propósito reservado, que no es otro que indicar "final de cadena" al igual que **^** significa "principio de cadena".